# How get all 'name' values in a json array?

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am making an application in Angular. I Have a Json file.
How get all 'name' values in the array?
Let's say that at the output I could get something like:

```
['Sony', 'Apple', 'Sony']
```

Json:

```
[
  {
    "Data": [
        {
            "name": "Sony",
            "color": "black"
        }            
    ] 
},
{
    "Data": [
        {
            "name": "Apple",
            "color": "white"
        }            
    ] 
},
{
    "Data": [
        {
            "name": "Sony",
            "color": "red"
        }            
    ] 
  }
]
```

app.component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import resData from '../assets/result.json';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.pug',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.styl']
})

export class AppComponent {
 tasks: any = resData;   
 console.log(this.tasks); //While displaying just array
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Comment: Your posted JSON code is not valid. Specifically, you have a single object inside the root array with repeated key "Data".

Comment: @ErnestoStifano, i'm so sorry. My mistake. Code UPD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function for this.

> let names = arr.map(element=> element.Data[0].name);

Note in here i assumed Data has only one instance.

```js
let arr = [
      {
        "Data": [
          {
            "name": "Sony",
            "color": "black"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Data": [
          {
            "name": "Apple",
            "color": "white"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Data": [
          {
            "name": "Sony",
            "color": "red"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
    
    let names = arr.map(element=> element.Data[0].name);
    console.log(names);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
 let x = [
            {
                "name": "Sony",
                "color": "black"
            }, 
            {
                "name": "Apple",
                "color": "white"
            },   
            {
                "name": "Sony",
                "color": "red"
            },
            {
              "name": "Sony",
              "color": "black"
          }, 
          {
              "name": "Apple",
              "color": "white"
          }  
              
    ];
    let output:any = [];
    let allNames = [];
    let uniqueNames = [];
x.forEach(element => {
  let index = output.findIndex(status => status.name === element.name);
  if(index>=0){
    let obj = output[index];
    obj.count = obj.count+1
    output[index]= obj;
  }else{
    output.push({name:element.name,count:1});
    uniqueNames.push(element.name);
  }

  allNames.push(element.name);
});
console.log(allNames);
console.log(uniqueNames);
console.log(output);
```